# Java - Search through object in a different method and print that method in the main method?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, search

I'm trying to search through an object saved in a different class by using a method, and then print the method output via the main method, but as of now it's not working. I'm getting errors in the main method saying `cannot make static reference to the non-static method.` I'm not supposed to be taking in Gerbil[] gerbilArray as a parameter but that's the only way I know for how to search through the object. Any help with printing or fixing my method?

**Here's my method line which searches through the object (so you know what I'm calling):**

```
public String searchForGerbil(String search, Gerbil[] gerbilArray) {
```

**Here's the line in the main method calling the method above:**

```
        System.out.println("Which gerbil would you like to search? (Enter lab ID)");
        String search = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println( searchForGerbil(search, gerbilArray) ); // I've also 
        break;  // tried searchForGerbil(search, Gerbil[]) but both are giving me
                // errors.
```

Comment: public static String searchForGerbil might help.

Comment: pete thanks. I wish you had posted an answer so I can mark it as correct. Stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: np. didn't think it was worth the mark:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your method static

```
public static String searchForGerbil(String search, Gerbil[] gerbilArray)
```

Static methods (such as main) belong to the class, not an instance of a class. You cannot call an instance method from a static method (context).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html